# How to drop dataframe rows when a field string value is on a list?

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with a million rows and 30 columns. One column is called OWNER and I have a list of OWNERs where I want to drop those records. This list is called drop_list. I'm trying  to make an index of rows to drop via

```py
drop_index = df[df['OWNER'] in drop_list].index
```

but I get

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Use: `df[df['OWNER'].isin(drop_list)].index`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
drop_index = sum([df['OWNER'] == x for x in drop_list]).astype(bool)
```

to get a series of boolean values containing `True` in rows that need to be dropped.

Or, using another approach,

```py
drop_index = [sum([df['velocity'] == x for x in drop_list]) == 0]
```

to get a series of boolean values containing `True` in rows to be kept.
The list with relevant rows dropped will be

```py
df_new = df[sum([df['velocity'] == x for x in drop_list]) == 0].reset_index(drop=True)
```

or shorter,

```
df[~df.OWNER.isin(drop_list)].reset_index(drop=True)
```